# Find SQL version of Azure server

Tags: azure-sql-database, bacpac

I have been restoring bacpacs provided by a third party on my on prem sql server via powershell. I copy over the bacpac from an SFTP site on to my local drive. This time I have been getting errors which lead me to believe that the bacpac has been created on a higher version of sql .
My on prem version is-

**Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5014356) - 15.0.2095.3 (X64)   Apr 29 2022 18:00:13   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)**

On enquiring with the third party they told me that the bacpac has been created on-

**Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Nov 16 2022 04:43:19   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation.**

How can i compare the 2 to find if the Azure version is higher ?

Comment: The azure version is always more up to date than the on-prem version.  But what is the specific error that you are seeing?  The Azure versions includes features that are only available in the Enterprise editions of SQL as well, so that may be a possibility.

Comment: The 3rd party just confirmed that the compatibility level on the Azure server is 150 so  it is SQL 2019  .                                                                                                                           This is the error when i run the powershell script - Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql160DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service